# How to Play & Joda: How to serialize and deserialize DateTime by Scala?

Tags: json, scala, serialization, playframework, deserialization

I'm using Play 2.3.7, Scala version 2.11.4.

I have this kind of class. I would like to serialize and deserialize object into json and from json to object.

```
             case class Person(var id: Int = 0,
                  var first_name: String = "",
                  var last_name: String = "",
                  var email: String = "",
                  var date_of_birth: DateTime = new DateTime())
```

After reading documents I found I need own implicit read and writer. So I tried as follows:

```
implicit val personWrites: Writes[Person] = (
  (__ \ "id").write[Int] ~
  (__ \ "first_name").write[String] ~
  (__ \ "last_name").write[String] ~
  (__ \ "email").write[String] ~
  (__ \ "date_of_birth").write[DateTime])
```

(unlift(Person.unapply))

```
 implicit val userReads: Reads[Person] = (
(__ \ "id").read[Int] ~
  (__ \ "first_name").read[String] ~
  (__ \ "last_name").read[String] ~
  (__ \ "nickname").read[String] ~
  (__ \ "date_of_birth").read[DateTime] 
 )(Person.apply _)
```

I get compiler error: overloaded method value apply with alternatives ......

Please inform me how to do it? Thanks!

Comment: This compiles for me. What is the exact error message? Did you define an apply method in the Person companion object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to write your own reads / writes unless they are not symmetric or you are doing something custom. [Json](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.json.Json$) has a format method that creates an formatter from case classes. It also has default formatters for some things including Joda DateTime classes.

```
implicit val personFormatter:Format[Person] = Json.format[Person]
```